# Does kafka include any schema registry version as part of avro messages?

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, kafka-producer-api

I am working on a kafka project, implementing a producer, and one of the requirements is: "Each message generated shall include the respective schema id and version of the schema registry"

Is this something that is supported out of the box in kafka or should I include it as part of our messages.

Note: I (as a producer) am the one to register the avdl files and topic that to the registry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka does not come with any Avro support, no.

Confluent, Apicurio, AWS Glue all provide AvroSerializer classes that do exactly this, depending on what registry server you're using for that ID lookup

Comment: Thank you. Indeed I see that the [wire format](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/fundamentals/serdes-develop/index.html#wire-format) contains a schema id. But I don't see a version inside it.  ("The Confluent Schema Registry based Avro serializer, by design, does not include the message schema; but rather, includes the schema ID" [ref](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/fundamentals/serdes-develop/serdes-avro.html) ). Should I add the schema version as part of the main message or is there any other Serializer to support this?

Comment: The registry server automatically maintains a version for you, based on a subject namespace. Ids meanwhile are globally unique and map to a version of a subject, therefore aren't required to be encoded within the record

Comment: "The registry server automatically maintains a version for you". Does this mean that when I add a schema in the registry under an existing subject name the registry somehow will increase the version for that schema?

Comment: @MarinosAn That is exactly what the Confluent Registry does. The version is for the subject. Use the API call `GET /subjects/:name/versions` to see the whole list